# Hibernate and Spring-boot too many database connection and high server load on 150 requests/second

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have spring boot application and I am using JPA and hibernate with oracle database. On high throughput 150 requests/second database stop allowing database connection and also database load goes unusually very high .

Here is my database configuration properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@<ip>:1521:<dbname>
spring.datasource.username=*******
spring.datasource.password=*******
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.initial-size=10
spring.datasource.maxActive=1200
spring.datasource.validationQuery=select 1 from dual
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
spring.datasource.pool-prepared-statements=true
spring.datasource.pool-prepared-statements-cache-size=250
spring.datasource.max-open-prepared-statements=250

spring.datasource.max-idle=50
spring.datasource.min-idle=10
spring.datasource.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=30000
spring.datasource.min-evictable-idle-time-millis=60000
spring.datasource.suspect-timeout=60
spring.datasource.log-abandoned=true
```

Here is the exception that I am getting

```
Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
    at net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$DelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:286)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy85.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:392)
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:434)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:687)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:247)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1102)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:320)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:150)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:133)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:370)
    ... 45 more
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:431)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:427)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringSpringInterceptor.invoke(MonitoringSpringInterceptor.java:73)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy133.updateDlrStatus(Unknown Source)
    at com.acl.otp.thread.DlrRequestHandler.updateDLRStatus(DlrRequestHandler.java:39)
    at com.acl.otp.thread.DlrRequestHandler.run(DlrRequestHandler.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1771)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:64)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:170)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:235)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
```

Comment: do you use any SQL/JDBC with the database connections or exclusively JPA?

Comment: @gorefest I am using exclusively JPA

Comment: Have you verified that the database is able to serve that load? You are using 1 DB Server, correct?

Comment: Yes I am using 1 db server and working on database configuration also.When there is high load kswapd and khugepaged services start running quite often. On database tranasparent_hugepages  is enabled and page size is by default 4k.  I am looking into enabling huge_Pages property to minimize swapping of pages. But 150 request/second for 8 core machine and 16 Gb RAM is nothing

Comment: this depends on the kind of query you are running. a server flood shows a similar kind of behaviour you described. in your position, I'd get myself a profiler and do a test run with it. I made very good experiences with Yourkit - easy to use plus you get a 30day trial.

Comment: I am using JavaMelody plugin with my project and it is giving less than 20ms for every query. The problem occurs on high load

Comment: What isolation level is configured in the database ?

Comment: I am managing isolation level from Spring code and it is "Read_Committed".

Comment: I have further investigated how memory is being used while putting load, when memory completely get exhausted then I get connection error. And I have found there is no significant changes in Page-in and Page-out but pagetables size increases considerably high

Comment: Ok, Read Committed ist fine. What pool sizes do you have configured in your connection pool?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be overloading the database server / service.

There is no general solution to this (no "magic bullet"), but you could look at things like:

- Limit the number of requests that you handle simultaneously.
- Use a profiler or other monitoring to figure out the types of request that are causing excessive database load, and seeing if they are amenable to optimization by:

  - Optimizing the SQL and/or the database schema
  - Reducing the number of queries
  - Caching results of common queries.
- Increase the resources (cores, memory, etc) available to the front end and / or the database; i.e. get bigger / faster machines.
- Switch to native SQL rather than using JPA.  (At least for the most heavily used queries.)
- Rearchitect your application so that it can be "scaled out"; e.g. replicating the front-end and backend, using a non-SQL database, etc.

Note that none of these is guaranteed to work in all circumstances

Answer (score 0):

the EntityManager related error occurs when the maximum connections reached to database. To resolve these type of errors "don't close session factory" in hibernate and close only session(must close) and make sure the "the connection pool size is less or otherwise leave to hibernate default connection pool size and use singleton design pattern to create sessionfactory object".